# Python Tkinter output the importet data from a text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text

i try to write the entered data from a text entry into a excel file.

if i do:

```
address = invoice_address_entry.get("1.0",END)
for item in address:
    worksheet.write(row, col, item)
    row +=1
```

i get the data as a column

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the symptoms,

```
address = invoice_address_entry.get("1.0",END)
```

returns a multi-line string. Iterating over a string yields the single characters in it.

If you want each line in it in a separate worksheet row, use `.splitlines()` first.

```
address = invoice_address_entry.get("1.0", END)
for item in address.splitlines():
    worksheet.write(row, col, item)
    row += 1
```

Comment: Your `for` loop has problems. You are reusing the `row` variable.

Comment: @TheLizzard Good catch, fixed.